# Mysql: How to insert into table using select where clause

Tags: mysql, insert

2 Works:

```
INSERT INTO data._top 
SELECT * FROM data.ops
WHERE ID = 'foo'
```

Works:

```
SELECT ID FROM data.table
```

How do I combine the above 2 statements using Mysql

```
INSERT INTO data._top 
SELECT  * FROM   data.ops
WHERE     (SELECT ID FROM data.table)
```

Comment: Could you explain further what exactly it is you would like to do? What do you want to SELECT from the table? What do you want to INSERT?

Comment: Plese, describe insert in english words.

Comment: Don't know if this is what you want as you don't actually tell us what you want, but the syntax for multiple ID's would be to use `WHERE ID IN (SELECT id FROM sometable)`

Comment: @ nanne: pls post as ans. I was using "exists" it worked In vs exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you possibly after something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `data._top`
    SELECT * FROM `data.ops`
    WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `data.table`);
```