# Approving and Denying MySQL and PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

1. This is  the deprecated MySQL.
2. Yes I know I should convert.
3. Please list helpful comments. (If you want a go at changing it to mysqli go ahead. :P)

For some reason, when I try to approve or deny a submission it wont. Example: User submitted ad. Approve | Deny You click on either the Approve button, or the Deny button, it takes you back to the staff panel, and the submission is still there and still in the submitted database instead of the ads database. (I run a directory advertising site.)

```
<?php 
$Page_Name = "Pending Submissions";
include("/home/idirecto/public_html/includes/global.php"); 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title><?=SiteName;?> - Staff Panel - <?=PageName;?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php 
include("./includes/javascript.php"); 
?>
</head>


<body>
<?php
if($logged_in && preg_match("/group(1)([^\d]|$)/", $user_info['group'])) {  
include("./includes/header.php"); 
include("./includes/sidebar.php"); 
?>

<section id="main" class="column">

<?php
$connection = mysql_connect($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass) or     die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db($DBname, $connection) or die(mysql_error());  
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $image = htmlentities($_POST['image']);
        $url = htmlentities($_POST['url']);
        $title = htmlentities($_POST['title']);
        $desc = htmlentities($_POST['desc']);
        $category = htmlentities($_POST['category']);
        $user = htmlentities($_POST['user']);
        $approve = isset($_POST['approve']);
        $deny = isset($_POST['deny']);
        $send_submit = isset($_POST['edit_submit']);
        $EmailFroms = "From: iDirectory <submit@idirectoryads.com>";
        $EmailTo = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
        $Subject = "iDirectory Submission";
        $validationOK=true;
        if (Trim($EmailTo)=="") $validationOK=false;

        if($deny){
            if (!$validationOK) {
                echo "<h4 class=\"alert_error\">An error occurred: The email address could not be validated.</h4>";
                include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
            } else {
                $Body = "Thank you for submitting your website to iDirectory. \n \n The site : $_POST[title] ($_POST[url]) \n has been denied submission. \n \n The reason your submission was denied could be that \n it contained content that does not pass our TOU. For more \n information please visit out support forum. \n http://www.support.idirectoryads.com \n \n Regards, \n iDirectory Staff \n --------------------------------------------------------- \n You received this as a result of submitting, a website \n into our database. We will not reveal or share your personal \n information without your permission.";
                $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $EmailFroms);
                $rt1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM submit WHERE id= '".$id."'");
                if ($success && $rt1){
                    echo "<h4 class=\"alert_success\">The submission has been denied.</h4>";
                    include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
                } else {
                    echo "<h4 class=\"alert_error\">An error occurred: The submission could not be denied.</h4>";
                       include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
                }
            }
        } else if($approve && $_POST['status'] == 'Edited'){ 
            if (!$validationOK) {
                echo "<h4 class=\"alert_error\">An error occurred: The email address could not be validated.</h4>";
                include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
            } else {
                $Body = "Thank you for submitting your website to iDirectory. \n \n Your requested updates to the site : $_POST[title] ($_POST[url]) \n has been approved. \n \n We thank you for your service. If you have any comments \n or questions feel free to visit our support forum. \n http://www.support.idirectoryads.com \n \n Regards, \n
                iDirectory Staff \n --------------------------------------------------------- \n You received this as a result of updating information you \n have submitting into our database. We will not reveal \n or share your personal information without your permission.";
                $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body,   $EmailFroms);
                $update_submission = mysql_query("UPDATE ads SET  title='".$title."', image='".$image."', url='".$url."', `desc`='".$desc."',  category='".$category."' WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $rt1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ads WHERE id=  '".$id."'");
                if($success && $update_submission && $rt1)
                {
                    echo "<h4 class=\"alert_success\">The submission has been approved.</h4>";
                    include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
                } else {
                    echo "<h4 class=\"alert_error\">An error occurred: The submission couldn't be approved.</h4>";
                    include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
                }
            }
        } else if($approve && $_POST['status'] == 'New'){ 
            if (!$validationOK) {
                echo "<h4 class=\"alert_error\">An error occurred:  The email address could not be validated.</h4>";
                include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
            } else {
                $Body = "Thank you for submitting your website to  iDirectory. \n \n The site : $_POST[title] ($_POST[url]) \n has been approved. \n \n We thank you for your service. If you have any comments \n or questions feel free to visit our  support forum. \n http://www.support.idirectoryads.com \n \n Regards, \n
                iDirectory Staff \n --------------------------------------------------------- \n You received this as a result of submitting, a website \n into our database. We will not reveal or share your personal \n information without your permission.";
                $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body,  $EmailFroms);
                $insert_submission = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ads  (title, image, url, `desc`, category, user) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$image."', '".$url."', '".$desc."', '".$category."', '".$user."')");
                $rt1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM submit WHERE id = '".$id."'");
                if ($success && $insert_submission && $rt1){
                    echo "<h4 class=\"alert_success\">The submission has been approved.</h4>";
                    include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
                } else {
                    echo "<h4 class=\"alert_error\">An error occurred: The submission couldn't be approved.</h4>";
                    include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
                }   
            }               
        } else {
            include("./includes/submission_pending.php");
        }
    echo "</section>"; 
    mysql_close($connection);
} else {
    include("./includes/login.php"); 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The header needs to stay the same as it's an API of a remotely hosted forum.

Question: If this has been updated to MySQLi does the rest of my code in every page have to be updated?

I've been at it for several hours, looking at documentation, changing the code, and still either I get a blank page, or does what the above code does.

If you need anymore coding let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: *"Question: If this has been updated to MySQLi does the rest of my code in every page have to be updated?"* --- Short answer: no / Long answer: Just as long as you didn't change any of the columns etc. or any included DB connection files, you should be ok. The included files which you appear to have, should not be used in the other files, since they risk in holding a different API; included accordingly.

Comment: I think you need to confirm that the parameters that you think are being passed by the form that calls this, are indeed being passed. Put a ton of `echo` statements and see what request you made (or just `print_r($_POST);`)

Comment: In the beggining of the file put print_r($_POST), and after submiting the Deny button copy what it outputs and paste in your post.

Comment: I have to say `$rt1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ads WHERE id=  '".$id."'");` this statement is invalid and also makes no sence. Would that explain why you are being sent to the wrong place?

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're right about that, although it is "somewhat possible", using a different method => http://stackoverflow.com/a/8871497/ and some of the examples on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html --- Just done slightly differently.

Comment: @ailvenge I try to put the print_r($_POST); into it, and it doesn't seem to give a log file at all. Where exactly should I add it in? I put it in the Very top PHP, and even in the values area, and still nothing.

Comment: @ailvenge Found it! It just gives this though. Array ( ) I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars` isn't even close to [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Updating all your pages wouldn't be a bad idea, since `mysql_query` is bad news if you've forgotten to escape things properly. The good news is you can go about cleaning up one file at a time so long as you have a new database framework to move to.

What you might do is pick something a little more modern to move to, like PDO, and incrementally strip out the old `mysql_query` code. So long as each page makes its own connection, like it does here, you'll be fine.

Going forward you'll want to have proper connection pooling to avoid the huge connection penalty on each page load. This is something [PDO does out of the box](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

As you overhaul your application, use something like `git grep mysql_query` as a metric for how much work left you have to do.

If you don't have a version control system or a testing server you'll want to get that set up before you start overhauling the application. Changing this sort of stuff is not always as easy as we'd like, so being able to revert mistakes and test the app is essential. Tools like [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) make it super easy to get a runtime that works fairly close to your production environment.

Comment: @Darkmage If you're in for a pretty serious overhaul, where you're going to have to gut and re-write a good portion of it, you might want to migrate to a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to give the new application more structure and make it easier to maintain. A framework provides a lot of support, and as database interfaces change, the framework will move you along almost effortlessly. Writing PHP by just slamming code into files isn't a scalable solution, and as you've seen, it's hard to upgrade.

Comment: I checked that site out, thanks! I'll check out and see what I can use.